# Why it is giving indices are out-of-bounds in keras?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

def preds(k):
    from datetime import datetime
    y_temp = np.zeros((len(test_vec), 3))
    y_pred = np.zeros((len(test_vec), 3))
    i=0;
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    kf = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=2)

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(data):
    print(data)
    print(target)
    print(train_index)
    print(test_index)
    K.clear_session()
    start=datetime.now()
    print('fold====================>>>>>>>>>>',i+1)
    #X_train , X_test = data[train_index].values, data[test_index].values
    #y_train , y_test = target[train_index].values, target[test_index].values
    a=np.asarray(data[train_index])
    b=np.asarray(data[test_index])
    c=np.asarray(target[train_index])
    d=np.asarray(target[test_index])

    model = None
    num_filters = [64, 128, 256, 512]
    model=vdcnn_model()

    early_stopping =EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
    bst_model_path = 'cv10_best_weights'+str(i+1) + '.h5'
    model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(bst_model_path, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)

    hist = model.fit(a, c, \
            validation_data=(b, d), \
            epochs=200, batch_size=256,callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint])

    bst_val_score = min(hist.history['val_loss'])
    print('bst_val_score',bst_val_score)

    #model.load_weights(bst_model_path)
    #model.fit(data, y,epochs=2, batch_size=256, shuffle=True,)

    #y_temp = model.predict([test_data], batch_size=256, verbose=1)
    #y_pred+=y_temp
    end=datetime.now()
    print(" ")
    print('time taken for this fold', end-start)
    i+=1
preds(2)

giving-
       IndexError                                Traceback (most recent    call last)
       <ipython-input-105-6de2161fc4d0> in <module>()
       ----> 1 preds(2)

       <ipython-input-104-bf8abb1717a0> in preds(k)
 17         #X_train , X_test = data[train_index].values, data[test_index].values
 18         #y_train , y_test = target[train_index].values, target[test_index].values
 ---> 19         a=np.asarray(data[train_index])
 20         b=np.asarray(data[test_index])
 21         c=np.asarray(target[train_index])

    IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

I have tried everything- .values, .asarray, .array,as_matrix() but still getting the same error.

Comment: what is the length of data, and what is the train_index when you get the error?

Comment: length of data-1440000, train_index-[ 720000  720001  720002 ..., 1439997 1439998 1439999]

Comment: Try data.iloc[train_index] instead everywhere.

Comment: @UpasanaMittal yup thanks it worked